# WiFi Scan No Such Instance field 'ChannelWidth'

Tags: java, android, wifi

Using

```
wifiManager.startScan();
ScanResultsList scanresultsList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

I obtain a list of scan results defined by `ScanResult` objects.

**Problem:**

Refering to `scanResult.channelWidth` I am presented with an error:

```
scanResult.channelWidth = No such instance field: 'channelWidth'
```

and

Exception

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No instance field channelWidth of type I
>   in class Landroid/net/wifi/ScanResult; or its superclasses
>   (declaration of 'android.net.wifi.ScanResult' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar)

Stacktrace:

```
06-14 02:57:19.732 27116-27116/com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector, PID: 27116
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No instance field channelWidth of type I in class Landroid/net/wifi/ScanResult; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.net.wifi.ScanResult' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
    at com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.main.initWiFiArrays(main.java:161)
    at com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.main.access$000(main.java:35)
    at com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.main$1$1.run(main.java:115)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I require this int value for further processing,

what is causing this no instance field?

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful,check this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html>

Comment: thanks, was using it all along, but they do not mention any of the sort restrictions on acquiring information like channelWidth